# Seaborn split column names for hue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, line-plot

I have a dataframe like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 4], [7, 8, 9, 4]]),
                   columns=['NP_A', 'NP_B', 'NP_C', "OP_A"])
```

I would like to use sns.lineplot.

But instead of the name of the columns as 'hue' I would like to make a split of the names.

```
"NP", "A"
"NP", "B"
...
```

In order to have a legend that considers the two combinations.

Comment: 1. Convert `df` to long form (which you'll need for plotting anyway): `dfm = df.melt()` 2. Split the string into a new column: `dfm['hues'] = dfm.variable.str.split('_', expand=True)[1]`

Comment: `dfm[['variable', 'hues']] = dfm.variable.str.split('_', expand=True)`